# Python checking if row is empty after slicing

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm working on a program that pulls data from an excel file and inputs in a calendar. In the excel file, dates are on the y axis. I'm iterating cell by cell across each row, but if the entire row is empty (aside from the date), I want to perform a different action than if just some of the cells in the row were empty. I cannot reference the header names directly as they will not always be the same.

In the example below, for row 1 I'm iterating 0, 2, nan, 4, nan
For row 2, I want to print('empty row') before moving to row 3.

```
Date    bx1 bx2 bx3 bx4 bx5
1        0   2       4
2                   
3        0   1   2   3   4
4        1   2   3   4   5
5                   
6                   
7        0   1   2   3   4
```

I've tried this:

```
if pd.isnull(m):
    print('emptyrow')
```

and this:

```
if pd.isna(df[1]):
    print('empty row')
```

Here's code for context:

```
layout = [[sg.In(key='-CAL-', enable_events=True, visible=False),
           sg.CalendarButton('Calendar', target='-CAL-', pad=None, font=('MS Sans Serif', 10, 'bold'),
                             button_color=('red', 'white'), format='%m/%d/%Y')],
          [sg.OK(), sg.Cancel()]]

window = sg.Window('Data Collector', layout, grab_anywhere=False, size=(400, 280), return_keyboard_events=True,
                   finalize=True)

event, values = window.read()
adate = (values['-CAL-'])
stu = (values[0])
window.close()

df = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\aelfont\\Documents\\python_date_test.xlsx', Sheet_name=0, header=None)

x = len(df.columns)    # length of bx
z = 1                  # used to determine when at end of row
b = 1                  # location of column to start summing
c = len(df.index)      # number of days in the month
r = 1                  # used to stop once last day of month reached
y = 1

# while date < last day in month, do action
# while the above is true, enter data until end of row
# once at end of row, submit and move to next row

while y < c:
    while z < x:
        n = int((values['-CAL-'][3:5]))
        m = df.iloc[n, b]
        z = z + 1
        b = b + 1
        if pd.isnull(m):
            ActionChains(browser) \
                .send_keys(Keys.TAB) \
                .perform()
            continue
        else:
            ActionChains(browser) \
                .send_keys(str(m)) \
                .perform()
        if z == x:
            z = 1
            b = 1
            n = n + 1
            y = y + 1
            time.sleep(5)
            yes = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('button.publishBottom:nth-child(2)')
            time.sleep(5)
            yes.click()
        else:
            ActionChains(browser) \
                .send_keys(Keys.TAB) \
                .perform()
    if y == c:
        break
if pd.isnull(m):
    print('emptyrow')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try the following:

```
if pd.isnull(m).all():
    print('emptyrow')
```

Full Code:

```
df = df.set_index('Date')
print(df)
for ind, row in df.iterrows():
    print(pd.isnull(row).all())
```

Output:

```
     bx1    bx2 bx3 bx4 bx5
Date                    
1    0.0    2.0 4.0 NaN NaN
2    NaN    NaN NaN NaN NaN
3    0.0    1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0
4    1.0    2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0
5    NaN    NaN NaN NaN NaN
6    NaN    NaN NaN NaN NaN
7    0.0    1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0

False
True
False
False
True
True
False
```

Comment: The output of the follow code yields the following error "None of ['Date'] are in the columns"

`df = df.set_index('Date')
for ind, row in df.iterrows():
    print(pd.isnull(row).all())`

When I use the code below, it includes the headers. The ouput I get is: False, false, true, false, false, true, true, false

 `df = df.set_index(0)
for ind, row in df.iterrows():
    print(pd.isnull(row).all())`

Comment: Incorporating your code, I got it to work. Working code is as follows: `print(pd.isnull(df.iloc[1, 1:6]).all())`